# php using a login to add and delete info

Tags: php, authentication, addition

I hope someone can point in the right direction, I'm doing a website in php with a login and once the user is logged in he can add or delete a paragraph.

What I want to do is, if I had open the website in the same computer but different browser (chrome and firefox) and I add a new paragraph in chrome how can I let know the user in firefox that a new paragraph is there ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Why don't just ask "tell me how to create web chat"?

Comment: because is not a web chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes much of a difference whether the different browsers are open on the same computer. You would have to refresh the content periodically using AJAX, for example.